# How to perform multiple string transformations using one transformer in FME Workbench?

Tags: fme-form, coordinate-system

I am converting a .DWG file to .GDB. All fields in DWG file are of Char type. The target .GDB needs to have some attributes in Float data type. For now, I am using one StringFormatter transformer for conversion of one attribute. That is cluttering the workspace.

Can we perform all Char to Float transformations using a single transformer?

Thanks

Comment: Is there maybe a way to do this using pyfme in a PythonCaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an option for using a Python Transformer in this situation.  If you're not comfortable with using python, then your best bet is to create a custom transformer consisting of the transformers that are changing the data types.  This will solve your initial issue of a cluttered Workspace.

To do this (This is from memory, I'm sorry if its incomplete.  Please use as a guide):

1. Select the Transformers that you would like to combine
2. Right mouse click on one of the transformers and select Custom Transformer.
3. FME should do the work for you.

Happy FMEing ;)

Answer (score 6):

As long as the Char fields all contain floating point numbers, then I doubt you would need to do this at all. FME doesn't generally care about data type within the transformation, and will only care about it on writing if the data doesn't match the required type.

i.e. as long as your char strings are all valid as floats, FME will do the conversion when the data is written.

Comment: Yes. You are very right, Mark. But I just wanted to somehow save space in Workspace.